# MVC Referencing strongly typed session objects on my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

According to various sources online i should use this

```
public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Get value. 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam> 
        /// <param name="session"></param> 
        /// <param name="key"></param> 
        /// <returns></returns> 
        public static T GetDataFromSession<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key)
        {
            return (T)session[key];
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Set value. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="session"></param> 
        /// <param name="key"></param> 
        /// <param name="value"></param> 
        public static void SetDataToSession(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key, object value)
        {
            session[key] = value;
        } 
    }
```

To make use of session objects in mvc.
I have made the following BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public int UserID
        {
            get { return Session.GetDataFromSession<int>("UserID"); }
            set { Session.SetDataToSession("UserID", value); }
        }
}
```

I now inherit the BaseController

```
 public class RequestsController : BaseController
    {
        private FooModel db = new FooModel ();

        // GET: Requests
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          var viewModel = Mapper.RequestIndex(UserID);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
}
```

And i can use the UserID session object without issue.

How do i use that same session object on my view, without adding it to the model.

```
<div class="clearfix">
                @if (Session["UserID"].ToString() == "1")
                {
        <div class="btn btn-default pull-right ">
            @Html.ActionLink("Super Special link for User 1", "sslfu1")
        </div>
                }
    </div>
```

The `Session["UserID"]` is incorrect here. What should i use?

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect`? Did you cross check if Session is being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my `SessionExtensions` class to include the following:

```
 public static T GetDataFromSession<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string key)
        {
            return (T)session[key];
        }
```

Then on the view reference it like this: `@Session.GetDataFromSession("UserID")`

It's not strongly typed , but this fits more naturaly

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to do this, one simple way is to make use of `ViewBag`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = Mapper.RequestIndex(UserID);
    ViewBag.UserID = UserID;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In the View you use it like this.

```
<div class="clearfix">
    @if (ViewBag.UserID == 1)
    {
        <div class="btn btn-default pull-right ">
            @Html.ActionLink("Super Special link for User 1", "sslfu1")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that i need to add it to the viewbag, i would like to avoid that.

Comment: @Stingervz You can use my second approach where I make use of extension method to get the `UserID` from the `Session`. Keep me updated.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to make it strongly typed you can use an extension method to act like a wrapper for getting `UserID`.

```
public static int UserID(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
{
    return session.GetDataFromSession<int>("UserID");
}
```

In the View

```
<div class="clearfix">
    @if (Session.UserID() == 1)
    {
        <div class="btn btn-default pull-right ">
            @Html.ActionLink("Super Special link for User 1", "sslfu1")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```